# React-Query and Query Invalidation Question

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I don't really know how to ask clearly but, I will paste my code first and ask below.

```
function useToDos() {
  const queryCache = useQueryCache();
  const fetchTodos = useQuery(
    'fetchTodos',
    () => client.get(paths.todos).then(({ data }: any) => data),
    { enabled: false }
  );

  const createTodo = async ({ name ) =>
    await client.post(paths.todos, { name }).then(({ data }) => data);

  return {
    fetchTodos,
    createTodo: useMutation(createTodo, {
      onMutate: newItem => {
        queryCache.cancelQueries('fetchTodos');
        const previousTodos = queryCache.getQueryData('fetchTodos');
        queryCache.setQueryData('fetchTodos', old => [
          ...old,
          newItem,
        ]);
        return () => queryCache.setQueryData('fetchTodos', previousTodos);
      },
    }),
  };
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to create my own custom hooks that wrap react-query functionality. Because of this, I need to set my `fetchTodos` query to be disabled so it doesn't run right away. However, does this break all background data fetching?

Specifically, when I run `createTodo` and the `onMutate` method triggers, I would ideally like to have the `fetchTodos` query update in the background so that my list of todos on the frontend is updated without having to make the request again. But it seems that with the query initially set to be disabled, the background updating doesn't take effect.

As I don't think wrapping react-query hooks into a library of custom hooks is a very great idea, I will probably have more questions about this same setup but for now, I will start here. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The mutation does not automatically triggers a refetch. The way to achieve this using react-query is via [queryCache.invalidateQueries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/api#querycacheinvalidatequeries) to invalidate the cache after the mutation. From the docs:

> The invalidateQueries method can be used to invalidate and refetch single or multiple queries in the cache based on their query keys or any other functionally accessible property/state of the query. By default, all matching queries are immediately marked as stale and active queries are refetched in the background.

So you can configure the `useMutation` to invalidate the query when the mutation settles. Example:

```js
function useToDos() {
  const queryCache = useQueryCache();
  const fetchTodos = useQuery(
    'fetchTodos',
    () => client.get(paths.todos).then(({ data }: any) => data),
    { enabled: false }
  );

  const createTodo = async ({ name ) =>
    await client.post(paths.todos, { name }).then(({ data }) => data);

  return {
    fetchTodos,
    createTodo: useMutation(createTodo, {
      onMutate: newItem => {
        queryCache.cancelQueries('fetchTodos');
        const previousTodos = queryCache.getQueryData('fetchTodos');
        queryCache.setQueryData('fetchTodos', old => [
          ...old,
          newItem,
        ]);
        return () => queryCache.setQueryData('fetchTodos', previousTodos);
      },

      onSettled: () => {
        cache.invalidateQueries('fetchTodos');
      }

    }),
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `invalidateQueries` and `refetchQueries`?

Comment: Look like `invalidateQueries` is just a better option of `refetchQueries`: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/521#issuecomment-644200235

Comment: No, actually, `refetch` will force the queries to fetch no matter what, whereas `invalidate` only push fetching when the queries are not being used. Sometimes we want either. They all have their own place.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your last comment that's not very clear in their doc indeed!

Comment: Curious, why invalidate `onSettled` instead of `onSuccess`?

Comment: @ChanceSmith my guess would be that queries that fail/error could still potentially have caused mutations on the server. As an illustration, a login attempt might disable after failing a certain number of times, causing changes in bits of state the client is currently using. Even if you don't have any such cases, it's still possible that that there were errors in the code, or a network issue occurred, causing a failure to be falsely reported. Of course, onSuccess will work fine in the majority of cases, and if your API is atomic then in almost all; in the end onSettled is a stronger guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting the logic into two different hooks? Instead of a monolith like `useToDos`?

That way you could have a hook for fetching:

```js
const fetchData = _ => client.get(paths.todos).then(({ data }: any) => data)

export default function useFetchTodo(
  config = {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: false
  }
) {
  return useQuery('fetchData', fetchData, config)
}
```

And in your mutation hook you can refetch manually, before `createTodo`

```
import useFetchTodo from './useFetchTodo'
//
const { refetch } = useFetchTodo()

// before createTodo
refetch()
```

Comment: Interesting setup. I am curious though why call refetch before creating a new item? From my understanding, if the query isn't disabled, whenever I'd create a new item, that query cache would update with it and my list of items in the UI would be updated. Am I missing something? Would I need to call refetch regardless (unless doing optimistic responses)?